# How to replace contents of a file with null/0s/1s in linux kernel 3.5 programming

Tags: c, linux, filesystems, kernel, system-calls

How can I erase a file's contents completely to 0s or 1s in the linux kernel 3.5 given its file name (path to it) as the only input parameter?

I studied the structure of the unlink system call and it after a lot of checking calls `int vfs_unlink(struct inode *dir, struct dentry *dentry)`

so from the *dentry how can I delete the file's contents? Or should I use `*dentry` at all?

**EDIT**

In response to the answers: I just want to overwrite the data. And I am *not* looking for a perfect result. I have progressed this far:

On one side: using vfs_unlink

I am confused at the following code:

```
error = security_inode_unlink(dir, dentry);
if (!error) {
error = dir->i_op->unlink(dir, dentry);
if (!error)
   dont_mount(dentry)
 }
```

Where is the actual unlink going on here?

Another approach: I just went ahead with writing the data using [write](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.6.2/fs/sysfs/bin.c#L139) system call:

I could not understand especially these lines:

```
 143        int size = file->f_path.dentry->d_inode->i_size;
 144        loff_t offs = *off;
 145        int count = min_t(size_t, bytes, PAGE_SIZE);

 151        if (size) {
 152                if (offs > size)
 153                        return 0;
 154                if (offs + count > size)
 155                        count = size - offs;
 156        }
 157
 158        temp = memdup_user(userbuf, count);

 162        mutex_lock(&bb->mutex);
 163
 164        memcpy(bb->buffer, temp, count);
 165
 166        count = flush_write(file, bb->buffer, offs, count);
 167        mutex_unlock(&bb->mutex);
 168
 169        if (count > 0)
 170                *off = offs + count;
 171
 172        kfree(temp);
 173        return count;
```

Can someone explain this to me? So that I can just write null to the file. my function may look like this.

```
static void write(struct file *file)
```

I need help with this. I am not asking for code, but I am lost currently.

Thanks

PS: I know perfectly well how to do this very simple thing in user-level program. But that is not my task. I have to do it in kernel space. And I need help with that (and especially understanding the code as I new to kernel programming).

Comment: Why are you asking? Leave the file management to the kernel file sub-system and to kernel file systems implementation. They do quite well. (and they also do disk buffering!).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I am asking as I have to do an assignment and this is a part of it. I am stuck

Comment: Are you coding a Linux user-land application (e.g. in C), or a kernel module??? If coding an application you should not care about the implementation details inside the kernel, since you can use the kernel only thru syscalls.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I am coding for kernel v3.5 ... Its in the VFS layer

Comment: Do you mean "for" the kernel (and that may mean in user-land) or "inside" the kernel (and that means a kernel module)? If you are doing a module, you should not do what you want to do. Or do you want to implement a new `erase_all_bytes_of_path(const char*filepath)` syscall?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I have to change the way system call unlink() works to completely remove the data instead of just the meta data.

Comment: Please edit your question to explain a bit better what you want to do and why. Also show what you tried.

Comment: @footy -- In short: There is no way to 100% completely remove all traces of the data short of reducing the device to dust.  Now, a simple overwrite and unlink will stop the MAJORITY of people from ever seeing the data, which is often good enough for personal documents and the like. However, with enough time and money you'd be amazed at what a determined data-recovery expert can do.  If you are storing top-secret data on the device then I'd recommend thermite.  I've learned putting the drive on a belt sander until there nothing but dust left works as well.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I have expanded my question to include more information. Please have a look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can do it easily with `write` system call.  The process is

1. Using `write` write NULL values to all the bytes of a given file
2. Delete the file using `unlink`.

Comment: That may be enough to stop a 'casual' looker, but it is far from secure.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher could you elaborate the security problem of it and how does this not answer OPs  question?

Comment: Andy's answer says it well.  The OP asked for `erased completely` which I would translate as `erased to the point of unrecoverable.`  Files overwritten with 0s can often still be recovered using anything from journaling traces, magnetic remnants on the "edges" of a hard drive's track, block remapping and the like.  This doesn't even cover file systems that have built in versioning and shadow copies.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im Ok guys lets take it down a tone :P I am a noob here. Could you please elaborate on how I can accomplish the 2nd task?

Comment: But `write(2)` and `unlink(2)` are syscalls, usable from a user-land application; apparently, the OP wanted to to that in kernel land (which, IMNSHO, is crazy).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Yes thats my assignment! I cannot do anything :P ...I have to do that in kernel land even though I know perfectly well how to do that in userland

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher I have changed the title so that its more clear to my question.

Comment: @footy if you know `write(2)` and `unlink(2)` will do the same but on user-space. why dont you see the source of these syscalls and just merge them?

Comment: @footy also read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6396119/write-file-from-kernel-land) SO question and this [link](http://kernelnewbies.org/FAQ/WhyWritingFilesFromKernelIsBad)

Answer (score 5):

There's no good answer here, and certainly not at the level of an individual file.  On simple filesystems (FAT, ext2) it's generally sufficient to simply open the file and overwrite it.  But that fails on almost all modern systems.  Modern filesystems can almost always be configured to journal data changes (though this is rarely default) and that data will live on in the journal until it happens to be overwritten in the future.  Even if you know the filesystem has "forgotten" the data the storage system may not -- consider the case of live backups, or of offlining a LVM volume.   Or the driver: NAND drivers routinely remap blocks as they are written, leaving "stale" content in place.  Or even the hardware itself: flash technologies like SSDs or MMC do exactly the same kind of block remapping, leaving your old data present for reads via JTAG, etc...

If you want to be sure that your data isn't on persistent storage, the only clean solution in the modern world is never to write it there in the first place.  Cache it in RAM, or write it to a tmpfs (that isn't backed by swap!), or come up with some kind of encryption scheme that makes sure storage compromise won't make it available to an attacker...

Comment: When in doubt, [degauss](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degaussing#Degaussing_magnetic_data_storage_media).

Comment: @Andy I have expanded my question to include more information. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Others have discussed the actual situation quite well, so I won't go there (and therefore don't bother modding this answer up, please). I just wanted to describe the code that confuses the OP.

First, this code is a snippet from `fs/namei.c:vfs_unlink()`:

```
error = security_inode_unlink(dir, dentry);
if (!error) {
    error = dir->i_op->unlink(dir, dentry);
    if (!error)
        dont_mount(dentry);
}
```

The `security_inode_unlink()` call first checks if the `current` (the current userspace process) has the required rights to remove directory entry `dentry` from directory `dir`.

Since Linux supports a number of different filesystems, and each filesystem (may) have their own inode operations, those operations are stored as function pointers in the struct inode (`dir`), `i_op` member structure. (Remember that a directory is very similar to a file, in that it contains the metadata for all entries contained in that directory. So having the operations be specific to a directory makes a lot of sense.)

The `dir->i_op->unlink(dir, entry);` simply calls the `unlink()` function for the directory `dir`. (Note that the `fs/inode.c:vfs_unlink()` does check that `dir->i_op->unlink` is non-NULL, before the snippet shown above.)

The final bit, `dont_mount(entry);`, is a helper function defined in `include/linux/dcache.h`, and simply marks `entry` to be "un-mountable", not accessible. (Directory entries are cached in dcache. Instead of having to ream the entry out of it, possibly a slow operation, this just marks it invalid. Sometime soon in the future, all stale dcache entries will be removed at once. It's very efficient this way, and quite simple, too, if you think about it.)

---

Sorry. I cannot help myself; I must add my spoon to the soup.

The problem is rather easy to solve, if you break it into manageable steps. If we assume this is for experimentation and learning only, not for security purposes -- for security you need *scrubbing*, not just clearing the contents --, then you need to do `open()`+`lseek()`+`ftruncate()`+`close()`, just in-kernel, right?

You don't want to use `write()`, because the filesystem-specific write functions require an userspace buffer. You'd need to allocate one (say, one page in length -- look at `mm/mmap.c:sys_old_mmap()` which calls the arch-specific `sys_mmap_pgoff()`), fill it with the data, write it into the file in a loop, then release the userspace buffer (using `mm/mmap.c:vm_munmap()`). Such a busy kernel loop is a big no-no; you'd need to move it into a worker thread..

No, it is much better to simply find out the length of the file, then truncate it to zero length, and re-truncate it to the desired length. That is the same as if you wrote zeros into it. Replacing the contents with anything but zero is just too much work, IMO.

For `open()`, call `filp_open()`. Remember, you only need the resulting `struct file *myfile`, not a file descritor, to manipulate a file in kernelspace.

For `close()`, you just call `filp_close(myfile, current->files)`. If you omit the file descriptor maintenance stuff for the `current` process, that is really the only thing left from `fs/open.c:sys_close()`.

For `lseek()`, you can just call `loff_t file_length = vfs_lseek(myfile, (off_t)0, SEEK_END);`. If you look at `fs/read_write.c:sys_lseek()`, that's what it does, after all.

For `ftruncate()`, look at `fs/open.c:do_sys_ftruncate()`, but remember to omit the file descriptor stuff. You already have the `struct file *myfile`, corresponding to the `struct file *file` in that function. Oh, and do remember you need to do it twice: first to zero length, then to `file_length` you obtained above.

Combining all the above seems to be a pretty feasible way to accomplish this -- assuming we all agree it is only useful for learning and experimentation, nothing practical.

Note that I did not really spend the time necessary to check all four syscalls (`sys_open()`, `sys_lseek()`, `sys_ftruncate()`, `sys_close()`) to check if there are any locking issues or race conditions I overlooked. You really should do that, because otherwise your experiment may oops your kernel (typical for race conditions). Do what I did, and start at the syscalls, then look at the functions -- and especially their comments, they usually mention if there are any locking requirements to calling that function -- to find out.